# How to solve a "simple" 6th grade match question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, volume

My daughter's homework tonight has stumped me I'm embarrassed to say on how to come up with an "easy" solution.

The ratio between the volumes of 2 rectangular prisms is 5:4.  The dimensions of the first prism are 3, 6, and 10.  What are the dimensions of the second prism?

We can get the volume of the 2nd prism as 144 from the ratio.  Now, because we need to multiply the number together 3 times, I can take the cube-root of the ratio (.8), which is ~.928 and multiply that against the original dimensions to get a volume of ~144.  But yikes!  There is no way 6th grade ratios should require that level of math.  What am I missing except perhaps shaking my head in shame at the authors of this problem.

Comment: Do the prisms have to be similar?  Otherwise you can use $3,6,8$.

Comment: The dimensions of the second rectangular prism is any set of 3 numbers, as long as their product is 144. The set 12; 3; 4 is an example.

Comment: yep, yep.  Right after I posted, it came to me.  Funny that.  Thanks for the help guys.  Wiping egg off face now...

Comment: You're a great dad!

Comment: If the ratio of the volumes is 5:4, doesn't that mean that the second rectangular prism has volume 225? (i.e. shouldn't a 4:5 ratio correspond to the second rectangular prism having volume 144?)

Comment: I might have posted it backwards, but from the problem, it definitely is 144.  I tried to abbreviate the Jack and Jill portions out of it to get to the meat of it.

Comment: @treble  The usual understanding of such ratios is "first quantity : second quantity".  If the problem had said, say, "_one_ of the prisms has dimensions...", without specifying which one, then certainly your proposal would also be admissible.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner When I see it, my mind wants to read "5*(first quantity) = 4*(second quantity)." As often happens, what my mind thinks is intuitive is backwards from the accepted standard...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And the answer is - only the volumes are in ratio, not the dimensions.  Dumb, dumb, dumb.  I successfully made it much harder than it needed to be.  144x1x1, 12x12x1, etc.

Comment: Perhaps the consequence of _too much_ experience -- I think many people dealing with a lot of problem-solving might have initially thought that _geometrically similar_ prisms were being asked for...  (This is where it is important to know who the intended "demographic" for the problem is.)

Comment: That is what my mind automatically jumped to as well as then there would only be 1 "correct" answer.  Silly infinite number of answers type question got me again.  :)